# Why images are disappearing on WordPress web site?

Tags: images, database, customization

I had this problem on 2 web sites (different versions of WP, different web hosts, different plugins), once in a while some images are disappearing from media library. Is it plugin-related issue, database, web host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Disappearing" means very little unless you can say the image file really disappeared from the server or if it's just a broken link you're seeing in page source or a bad link in the DB.

Little help can be offered unless you look in logs and see errors, ask your host about problems and nail down the similarities and differences between the two instances of missing images, versions of WP and plugins.

Comment: how do I find and look in the logs and see errors?

Comment: Depends on your host. For example, on GoDaddy see here http://help.godaddy.com/article/1197

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will check that. So in other words images can't just disappear from WP unless there are errors on the servers?

Comment: @alexndm: nothing happens without a reason. Images don't disappear unless there's host disk corruption, DB crash, file changes, permalink changes, etc.